# Populating combobox in CodeNameOne

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox, codenameone

I'm having a slight problem when populating a combobox from the column of a database. below is my code:

```
protected void initComboBoxModel(final ComboBox cmp) {

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM stockinfo";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        Vector vec = new Vector();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String item = rs.getString("Parts");
            Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
            h.put("cmp", item);
            vec.addElement(h);
            cmp.setModel(new DefaultListModel(vec));
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Dialog.show("Error", "initComboBoxModel count not populate the combo box.", "OK", null);
    }
    }
```

The combobox populates but there is unnecessary text in each option in the combobox, for example:

an option which should say "Hello" says "{cmp = Hello}".
How do i stop this from happening? it occurs for every item in the combobox.

Thanks in advance:)

Marko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are creating a `Vector<HashTable>` so when you are populating the combobox the default renderer takes `toString()` method from each hashtable.

I don't know why you need a hashtable, but that's the problem why you are stuck.

Im not familiar with codeNameOne but in swing `JComboBox` by default uses a renderer wich uses `toString()` method to display object data. So you can make your own renderer class to customize the view.

**UPDATE**

I modify your code and comment code, assuming you are using java 1.5 or above.

```
protected void initComboBoxModel(final ComboBox cmp) {

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM stockinfo";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        Vector<String> vec = new Vector<String>(); // use generics 
        while (rs.next()) {
            String item = rs.getString("Parts");
            vec.addElement(item);            
        }

        cmp.setModel(new DefaultListModel(vec)); // here you set the model

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Dialog.show("Error", "initComboBoxModel count not populate the combo box.", "OK", null);
    }
 }
```

Now it's gonna to work you don't have to use any renderer cause you add Strings so `toString` method is fine in this case.

Comment: thank you for your quick response, i'm just a little confused as to how to add this to my code now.The code I posted is in a method as shown below. How do I incorporate your code into mine?

Comment: protected void initComboBoxModel(final ComboBox cmp) {
      
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM stockinfo";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            Vector vec = new Vector();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String item = rs.getString("Parts");
                Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
                h.put("cmp", item);
                vec.addElement(h);
                cmp.setModel(new DefaultListModel(vec));
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
        }

Comment: @user2672736 update the question to add proper code with proper indentantion , i can't guess, in your actual code you are setting the model inside the while loop and that's not good.

Comment: I updated the code, oh right i should set the model at the end of the method?

Comment: That answer is incorrect, this isn't a Swing question its a Codename One question

Answer (score 0):

It won't work for you on the device, you changed the classpath to add JDBC which you shouldn't have.

You should use a renderer or a MultiList to have the hashtable entries render correctly.